# How to train a neural network with symmetrical output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am attempting to train a neural network to predict output that is symmetric with respect to certain operations. It seems to me this creates a problem for training, because there are multiple equally acceptable answers. An example of a task that has this problem is prediction of the normal vector to a surface based on a cloud of points: $\vec{n}$ and $-\vec{n}$ are equally valid answers. What is the proper way to account for this? I have defined my loss function to return the distance from the "closest" correct answer, but still my model is unable to achieve any degree of accuracy.

[This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/93185/training-a-neural-network-with-two-possible-correct-outputs-for-one-input) question is similar to mine, but never received a satisfactory answer. One comment suggests comparing model output to whichever of two equivalent outputs would yield the lowest loss to calculate the loss function (which I have already done), and the only answer suggests to instead have the model predict both (equivalent) outputs. This unfortunately has the same problem: if $a$ and $b$ are the correct outputs, then the model outputs $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ are once again equally valid.